# Float type field in Model while automatically created in database as real type?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, floating-point

Iam using mvc4 .I have a model .In that model i created a field called  "AllFuels" of data type Float.
But when the table automatically created in the database the data type of the field  "AllFuels"  is real.Iam using model first method .Can anyone know the reason why this is happening?

```
public float AllFuels { get; set; }
```

But this field in the table created as real datatype.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... why this is happening?

Well, that's easy - because this is the mapping that is programmed into EF.

**Does it matter?**

Look at the following:

- [SQL Server BOL: float and real (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx):

  - -3.40E + 38 to -1.18E - 38, 0 and 1.18E - 38 to 3.40E + 38
  - 4 bytes storage
  - The ISO synonym for real is float(24).
  - 7 digits precision
- [float (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx)

  - -3.4 × 10<sup>38</sup> to +3.4 × 10<sup>38</sup>
  - 7 digits precision
  - 32-bit storage (4 bytes)

So the "*approximate range*" <sup>†</sup> is the same for both, as is the storage amount: they are both 32-bit floating binary point types. The annoying thing is that .NET float is not specifically mentioned in the [BOL reference for data type conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729.aspx), which makes it hard to quickly look this up <sup>‡</sup>.

In addition, `Edm.Float` is listed in the Edm data types ([MSDN: Conceptual Model Types (CSDL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399548%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) as a floating point with 7-digit precision, so that matches up with float in .NET and real in SQL server ([CSDL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399292%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is the XML language that describes entites, relationships etc. and is [used by EF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj652004.aspx)).

**So what should I do?**

What do Microsoft say about floating point in ADO.NET? If you read: [MSDN - Data Type Mappings in ADO.NET (Floating-Point Numbers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399304.aspx) they say "test". So do that, and if this precision is not enough for you, then your .NET type needs to be a `double` instead, which should become a higher precision type in SQL Server (it would translate to `float(53)`, I believe)

---

<sup>†</sup> *I couldn't quickly find the IEEE reference, so I will point you at [wikipedia for the definition of "approximate range"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Range_of_floating-point_numbers).*

<sup>‡</sup> **Edit** Guru [Lasse V. Karlsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/267/lasse-v-karlsen) is totally right to ask me to qualify this statement: [`Single` is equivalent to `float`,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) my badly expressed point was that you have to know to look for `Single` rather than `float` to be able to find the information in the reference.

Comment: What do you mean by "Not explicitly mentioned"? Real maps to Single (keyword `float` in C#) according to that table.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen. You are right, it does mention it, it just doesn't make it easy for people who don't instictively know that `Single` is `float` (I'm not sure if it should have to, fwiw). My comment about "_specifically mentioned_" was that you have to do more than Ctrl+F5 for "float" on that page.